# Angular Directives 2 way binding & refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, isolate-scope

Let's say you have a page where you have a directive for customer search (1st directive).
You do a search and you get back a list of customers from a web server.

Now, inside the directive above, you have a 2nd directive, let's call it `customerRes`, that displays some info for the customers (this is like a small widget reused in many places in your site). Inside the isolated scope of this 2nd directive I have an attribute called `results` that I bound from the results returned e.g.

The 1st directive has a declaration like

```
<customer-res results="webserverResult">
```

and inside the `customerRes` directive I have something like a

```
<div ng-repeat="x in results>
{{name}} {{bla}}  ... bla bla
</div>
```

Now everytime the user clicks the parent directive, it will make a request to the web server and perhaps get different results back.

The question: Does angular actually monitor itself that the value bound to the isolated scope changed outside the directive, or do I need to do something to make sure that it invalidates?

Also, even if you load your page before the results get back, once they get back shouldn't they update the page elements?

Comment: I recommend to post the code of your directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cool way is you will find out for yourself. Don't get me wrong, but personally I did this when walking my first steps in angular. Helps to understand the framework more deeply rather reading the docs and forget more easily.

You can always add

```
scope.$watch('myVariable', function(value) { 
  console.log('myVariable changed to:', value);
})
```

to your directives and see when its value changes.

Two-way-bindig works like a charm, even on full page reloads. Cannot be more precise without your directive's JS code. But when using isolated scopes, probably directives need

```
scope: {
   myVariable: '='
}
```

```
<my-directive my-variable="results.entries"></my-directive>
```

But keep in mind, that when reloading the page, angular restarts from zero. Meaning for each directive its link function is called once and many many other things under the hood. Keyword is angular's `digest cycle`.

Hope I could help with this (a bit more broad) answer.

Comment: So even though I would be retrieving (via an http service) the actual results array one level above the directive, 2 way binding should still work without the need to use $apply or something like that, correct? I am not @ work right now and the problem is that the chunk I have the problem has a lot of custom dependencies. I would have to write something new ( might do tomorrow and update thje post). Oh and by the way thank you for the support.

Comment: as long as the variable stays the same reference, roughly you are correct. Angular has many places, where it applies the scope (trigger of the digest cycle) automatically. e.g. ```ng-click```, ```ng-model``` etc. see this article: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/. I would be happy if you vote my answer as soon you have rep.

Comment: Turns out I had it correct, but if you bind something to 'results' and instead u type 'resluts', it is not the framework's fault. Thank you ALL for your help, much appreciated and also thanks for the link.